# Why and when should we use pointer-to-pointer instead of simple pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I understand how pointers to pointers work, but I can't understand **why using pointers to pointers over simple pointers**, and when using them in **C programming** (not C++). I've read a lot of posts about it, but I can't found a satisfying answer. All examples I've seen can be turned into a one-level pointer solution. Can someone give an simple example where pointers to pointers are "mandatory" (that can't be done with simple pointers) ?

Comment: Pointers are commonly used to emulate *pass by reference* to functions. I.e. you pass a pointer to a variable to a function, and the function can dereference the pointer to set the value of the variable. Now imagine doing this for a variable that is a pointer. Another common case, dynamically allocating a "2d array".

Comment: I used this technique [in an HTTP parser, to avoid copying the data](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/87dd5e918ee9edec82f8ffc13bf72940583253e2/src/http/http1_simple_parser.c#L191-L307)... a pointer to [a collection of pointers (using a `struct`)](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/87dd5e918ee9edec82f8ffc13bf72940583253e2/src/http/http_request.h#L25-L91) was passed to the parsing method, and the parsing method made sure the pointers would point to the correct area in the memory for the actual data... there are simpler example too.

Comment: You *could* transform any program to only use a single level... but it would make the code uglier.  The pointer-to-pointer clearly expresses the concept of holding the address of another pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you’ve probably seen is

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv )
```

In this case, `argv` is a “ragged” two-dimensional array, that is, each row of the array stores a pointer to a one-dimensional array of varying size.

The other common case is the one everyone else has mentioned so far: you want the function to modify a pointer variable.  An example of this from POSIX is the function

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

This function allocates a memory block of at least `size` bytes, aligned to `alignment`.  But its return value is an error code.  The pointer to the newly-allocated block of memory is written to `*memptr`.  An example of usage might be:

```
static const size_t page_size = 4096; // Could get this value from sysconf().

void* new_copy_of_page( const void* const old_page )
/* Copies the page of memory at old_page to a new page of memory (aligned to
 * the page size).  This new page must be freed with free().  Returns a pointer
 * to the new page, or NULL if out of memory.
 */
{
  void *new_page = NULL; // Set by posix_memalign() to a new memory page.

  assert(old_page); // Check for valid input. 

  if ( 0 != posix_memalign( &new_page, page_size, page_size ) )
    return NULL; // Or handle out-of-memory error.

   // Otherwise, the allocation was successful.
   memcpy( new_page, old_page, page_size );
   return new_page;
}
```

This is a somewhat contrived example, because the standard library now has `aligned_alloc()` with the same functionality and a simpler interface.

Comment: Figred I might as well rewrite to pass data as a parameter and not a global variable, since this is supposed to be an example of good style.

Answer (score 3):

A simple is a case where you want to modify the pointer itself. For example,

```
void func(char **p)
{
   *p = malloc(1024); / allocate 1024 bytes */
}

int main(void)
{
   char *p = NULL;
   func(&p);
   /* Now, p points at memory block of 1024 bytes and do something with it */

   return 0;
}
```

Of course, it's possible to do this memory allocation via another methods such as returning a pointer from the function etc. But this is one way where the pointer to pointer is useful.

Comment: and what about if you want to initialize two pointers? you can only return one of them... :)